# Material-UI v1: Using the custom colors for theme configuration

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This should be a pretty simple thing but I am pretty new to material-ui.I am using material-ui v1 and I am trying to change the primary color of the theme. This is how my theme object looks like without using the custom color:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui-next/styles';
import blue from 'material-ui-next/colors/purple';
import green from 'material-ui-next/colors/green';
import red from 'material-ui-next/colors/red';


const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: green, 
        secondary: {
          ...green,
         },
       error: red,
     },
});


export default theme;
```

In the primary color, I wanted to use my custom color which is '#6699CC'. If I assign primary:'#6699CC', it gives me following error :

> "Material-UI: primary color is missing the following hues:
>   50,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,A100,A200,A400,A700,contrastDefaultColor
>   See the default colors, indigo, or pink, as exported from
>   material-ui/colors. warning @ bundle.js:37805"

This was used to work in 0.19 beta release but it does not work with V1-beta. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check documentation for [Color](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/ceb6637eeafb555143d77c5efb9e1db4606d4144/docs/src/pages/style/color.md#examples). You need to set hue while selecting colors I think.

```
import { red, purple } from 'material-ui/colors';

const primary = red[500]; // #F44336
const accent = purple['A200']; // #E040FB
```

**Update:**
As I read from the [docs](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/customization/themes/#the-other-variables) you might need to set hue and color value together so material-ui can know which color it needs to render.

Try to set your primary color according to the JSON object below.

```
{
    primary: {
      50: "#e3f2fd",
      100: "#bbdefb",
      200: "#90caf9",
      300: "#64b5f6",
      400: "#42a5f5",
      500: "#2196f3",
      600: "#1e88e5",
      700: "#1976d2",
      800: "#1565c0",
      900: "#0d47a1",
      A100: "#82b1ff",
      A200: "#448aff",
      A400: "#2979ff",
      A700: "#2962ff",
      contrastDefaultColor: "light"
    }
}
```

**PS:** You are trying to `import blue` from `/colors/purple`

Comment: Thanks, Benny. Appreciated. The problem is I can not find #6699cc hue in the color pallet: [link](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/style/color/#color-palette).What should I do?

Comment: If you want to use a custom Hex color I think you can just set primary to that hex since `red[500]` returns a hex value too. Colors module is just for making it simpler if you want to use Material-UI Colors.

Comment: I understand but setting primary to hex `code  primary:'#6699CC' `code` gives an error _italic_"Material-UI: primary color is missing the following hues"_italic_. This was used to work in 0.19 but does not work anymore with v1. Can you please tell me if I am making a mistake here or is this a bug with v1?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on my own project. Material ui can make the pallete hues for you, just supply light/main/dark properties with the color you want to use. See https://material-ui.com/style/color/

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { yellow, orange } from '@material-ui/core/colors';

const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#ea212d',
    },
    secondary: yellow,
    error: orange,
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily:
        'roboto, sans-serif',
  },
});

export default muiTheme;
```

Comment: this is for use in material-ui v1

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      // light: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      main: '#ff4400',
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      // contrastText: will be calculated to contrast with palette.primary.main
    }
  }
}
```