# How to use custom colors in material-ui@next (v1)

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to set the primary theme color value to a custom color (hex code). I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080719/material-ui-v1-using-the-custom-colors-for-theme-configuration) which says I need to set my primary color to the JSON object mentioned there.

This doesn't make sense to me, why do I have to build such an object myself? Would it not make more sense to convert (e.g. when given a hex value) to HSL and adjust the hue value as needed? Inside the library of course, so I only need to pass a hex value.

My second question is, why does this JSON object have values above 360 degrees? As for my understanding, these values represent the hue value from the HSL color space ...

Comment: Have you reviewed the docs? https://material-ui-next.com/style/color/

Comment: I did but it doesn't really help imo. Even with [Google's Color Tool](https://material.io/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0) you cant get the exact values for each hue.

Comment: looks like the docs helped.  Glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created my custom colors using [this tool](http://mcg.mbitson.com/#!?mcgpalette0=%233f51b5). You can use it directly in your theme config like so:

```
import createPalette from 'material-ui/styles/createPalette';

export const blue = {
    50: '#e8eaf6',
    100: '#c5cbe9',
    200: '#9fa8da',
    300: '#7985cb',
    400: '#5c6bc0',
    500: '#3f51b5',
    600: '#394aae',
    700: '#3140a5',
    800: '#29379d',
    900: '#1b278d',
    A100: '#c6cbff',
    A200: '#939dff',
    A400: '#606eff',
    A700: '#4757ff',
    'contrastDefaultColor': 'light',
};
export default {
    palette: createPalette({
        primary: blue
    })
};
```